# Is there an event when custom plugin is being installed?

Tags: magento, plugins, installation

I want to know if there is some sort of event which I can use the observer for to detect when my plugin is being installed?

I want to check the Magento configuration when my plugin is installed and prevent enabling it when the media storage is set to database.

I have the observer and have no idea to which event connect it.

@Following `OSdave` Here is my config.xml :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>            
        <resource>
            <module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>My_Module</module>
                </setup>
            </module_setup>
            ...
```

I have my install script at :

`app/code/comunity/My/Module/data/module_setup/data-install-1.0.php`

I am using Magento 1.8.

Comment: why don't you check during the resource install script?

Comment: can you give me a hit how to check it ? i just started learning magento

Comment: you say "media storage is set to db", but I don't know what you're refering to.... unless you meant "**session** storage"

Comment: with this line `Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->checkDbUsage()` i can check if media storage is set to database
and if so i want to prevent my plugin instalation until user change it to Filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your install setup script, you can do something like:

```
<?php

/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

if (Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->checkDbUsage()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('yourmodulehelper')->__('unable to install plugin'));
} else {
    //execute your script
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

HTH

Comment: but i can't make my script run. i have no entry at `core_resource` for my module version :( also i have cash disabled and script wont run. Updated my question for setup config.

Comment: the `<resources>` tag needs **s** at the end, plural

Comment: perfect answer! xD was fighting this since 4 and half hour now xD